# Data not being displayed on the file

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with the print statement when i run the macro the macro is not writing into the file.
I get a blank file with no data inserted into the file can anybody tell hats wrong in this.

```
Sub sample()
    Open "C:test.txt" For Output As #2
    Dim a As String
    a = "hi"
   print #2, a
End Sub
```

Comment: probably the path to the file? `C:\test.txt` ?

Comment: even after the modification of file path the data is not being displayed @vba4all

Comment: You should close the file, if you are ready: `Close #2`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is relevant but you should not assume file number 2 is available. You should use `FreeFile` to get the next free file number.

The real problem is likely to be "C:test.txt".  This means: write "test.txt" to the current directory within drive C. The current directory is probably not what you think it is.

I have created an amended version of your macro:

- I have closed the file as Axel suggests.  Excel will clean up after you so this is not essential but it is always better to do your own housekeeping.
- I have used `FreeFile` as I suggest.
- I have added two `Debug.Print` statements to output data to the Immediate Window.  The first outputs the file number which will probably be 1.  The second outputs the current directory which is probably "C:\YourUserName\Documents".
- I have amended the Open statement so the file is written to the folder containing your workbook.

Hope this helps.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sample()

  Dim FileNum As Long

  FileNum = FreeFile

  Debug.Print "File number " & FileNum
  Debug.Print "Current directory " & CurDir

  Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.txt" For Output As #FileNum
  Dim a As String
  a = "hi"
  Print #FileNum, a

  Close FileNum

End Sub
```